# I can't make multiple statement to check two statement

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I am making a code in python to make password and save in the text file, if the user enters the same password in the file, the error code will appear. The problem is that although I made a two statement to check the password is valid and there is no same password in the text file, the statement of the one that will check text file to find same file. Can you tell me where I get mistake?

```
def InputString():
    String = str(input("Enter your password. :"))

    return String

def CheckPassword(Password):
    ##I declared "Index","Upper","Lower","Digit" and "Other" as Integer.
    ##In python, there is no data type for
    ##"char", so We use string instead.
    ##I use "variable" as boolean for checking password.
    Upper = 0
    Lower = 0
    Digit = 0
    Other = 0
    variable = False
    for index in range(len(Password)):

        NextChar = (Password[index:index+1])
        if NextChar >= "A" and NextChar <= "Z":
            Upper = Upper + 1
            elif NextChar >= "a" and NextChar <= "z":
            Lower = Lower + 1
        elif NextChar >= "0" and NextChar <= "9":
            Digit = Digit + 1
        else :
            Other = Other + 1

    if Upper > 1 and Lower >= 5 and (Digit - Other) > 0:
        variable = True
    else :
        variable = False

    return variable

def CheckThrough (Password):
    FileP = open("Password.txt","r")
    if FileP.mode == 'r':
        contents = FileP.read()
        if contents == Password:
            usable = False
        else :
             usable = True
    FileP.close()

    return usable


###The main programs starts here###

print("Enter the password.")
print("You must add at least 1 upper character.")
print("5 lower character")
print("and the difference between numeric character and symbols must be more than 1.")
variable = False
usable = False

while variable == False and usable == False:
    Password = InputString()
    variable = CheckPassword(Password)
    if variable == True:
        usable = CheckThrough(Password)
        if usable == True:
            print("You can use the password.")
        elif usable ==False :
            print("The password you entered is already used.")
        else :
            print("The error is ocuured.")
    else :
        print("You can't use this password, try again.")

print("Your password is",Password)

FileP = open("Password.txt","a+")
FileP.write(Password)
FileP.write("\n")
FileP.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `.strip()` so it has no spaces e.g `String = str(input("Enter your password. :").strip())`. When you enter in the password there's a space but that doesn't get saved to the file thus it always reads it as a new password.

my input = Enter your password. :Kingdom1hearTs

The input into the program = " Kingdom1hearTs"

(used print to see what was being entered into the system)

and the `if contents == Password:` needs to be `if Password in contents:`otherwise your seeing if Password is the same as the whole txt file.

```
NextChar = (Password[index:index+1])
        if NextChar >= "A" and NextChar <= "Z":
            Upper = Upper + 1
        elif NextChar >= "a" and NextChar <= "z": #had the wrong indentation
            Lower = Lower + 1
        elif NextChar >= "0" and NextChar <= "9":
            Digit = Digit + 1
        else :
            Other = Other + 1
```